# vector on c++ as a member into a class

Tags: c++, class, vector, methods, properties

I have a problem in which `getUserOpinionVector()`, `getAppConstructorVector()`, `setUserOpinionVector()`, `setAppConstructorVector()` can't access the `UserOpinionVector`, `AppConstructorVector` properties.

Any suggestion ?

I pasted my code below.

**Note :** constructors and some properties and methods where skipped for simplicity.

#### .h file on c++ :

```
#ifndef APPLICATION_H
#define APPLICATION_H
#include "ApplicationConstructor.h"    
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Application{  
  private:
   ApplicationConstructor &AppConstructor;
   UserOpinion *UserView;
  public:
   Application(char *, string, string, ApplicationConstructor &, UserOpinion &, float); // Application's Constructor
   Application(const Application &); // Copy Constructor     
   vector<ApplicationConstructor &> getAppConstructorVector(); // Get the Application Constructor Vector
   vector<UserOpinion *> getUserOpinionVector(); // Get the User Opinion Vector       
   void setAppConstructorVector(vector<ApplicationConstructor &>); // Set the Application Constructor Vector
   void setUserOpinionVector(vector<UserOpinion *>); // Set the User Opinion Vector  
   virtual ~Application(); // Destructor
  protected:
   vector<ApplicationConstructor &> AppConstructorVector; // Vector with Application Constructor Objects
   vector<UserOpinion *> UserOpinionVector; // Vector pointers to with User Opinion Objects   
   };
   #endif /* APPLICATION_H */
```

#### cpp file :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Application.h"

//Constructor
Application::Application(char *applicationCode, string applicationName, float applicationVersion, 
                     ApplicationConstructor &appConstructor , UserOpinion *userComment, float price ):AppConstructor(appConstructor){
if ((this->AppConstructor != NULL) && (this->UserView != NULL ))
{
    this->addToAppConstructorVector(this->AppConstructor);
    this->addToUserOpinionVector(this->UserView);
}
}

// Set the Application Constructor Vector
void setAppConstructorVector(vector<ApplicationConstructor &> appConstructorVector){
   this->AppConstructorVector = appConstructorVector;
}

// Set the User Opinion Vector  
void setUserOpinionVector(vector<UserOpinion *> userOpinionVector){
   this->UserOpinionVector = userOpinionVector;
}

// Get the Application Constructor Vector
vector<ApplicationConstructor &> getAppConstructorVector(){
  return this->AppConstructorVector;
}

// Get the User Opinion Vector
vector<UserOpinion *> getUserOpinionVector(){
 return this->UserOpinionVector;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The functions should be defined as member functions of the class `Application`.

It means that you should add `Application::` before each function names like this:

```
// Set the Application Constructor Vector
void Application::setAppConstructorVector(vector<ApplicationConstructor &> appConstructorVector){
   this->AppConstructorVector = appConstructorVector;
}

// Set the User Opinion Vector  
void Application::setUserOpinionVector(vector<UserOpinion *> userOpinionVector){
   this->UserOpinionVector = userOpinionVector;
}

// Get the Application Constructor Vector
vector<ApplicationConstructor &> Application::getAppConstructorVector(){
  return this->AppConstructorVector;
}

// Get the User Opinion Vector
vector<UserOpinion *> Application::getUserOpinionVector(){
 return this->UserOpinionVector;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use your function unless you declare it on your class, thats why you cant access it

```
// Set the User Opinion Vector  
void Application::setUserOpinionVector(vector<UserOpinion *> userOpinionVector){
   this->UserOpinionVector = userOpinionVector;
}
```

Try adding the name of the class first, also add the function as public on your header file

```
class Application{  
  private:
   ApplicationConstructor &AppConstructor;
   UserOpinion *UserView;
  public:
   ....
   void setUserOpinionVector(vector<UserOpinion *> userOpinionVector)
```

Hope it helps